# String returns in finally and try block

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

I came across this question and I am unable to understand the reason of the output it is giving.

The program is:

```
public static String method(){

    String s = new String();
    try
    {
        s = "return value from try block";
        return s;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        s = s + "return value from catch block";
        return s;
    }
    finally
    {
        s = s + "return value from finally block";
    }

}
```

The output is:

> return value from try block

Now, I debugged it and the value of `s` at `return s` statement in `try` block was `return value from try block`, `return value from catch block` after it `returned from finally block`.

Still the output is :

> return value from try block

Can any one please explain this behavior?

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/does-finally-always-execute-in-java

Comment: I think you'll find more clarification here [Try-catch-finally-return clarification - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225819/try-catch-finally-return-clarification)

Comment: The answer would be from oracle documentation:
"The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs."
check this refrence : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let us understand how Java handles method calls.
There is separate stack memory for every thread. When we call any method, Java internally inserts a record at top of the stack. The record contains some details like parameters & object etc.

Here one interesting field is there: the return value. Whenever​ the return statement is encountered, the field is updated. Now observe the code.

In the `try` block, the return value field is set to the return value from the `try` block. Now as per the execution sequence the `finally` block is executed. Now the `finally` block modifies the string reference `s`. It didn't modify the `return value` field which is previously settled by try block. Finally​ the method call completed & Java internally pop the record & return the return value field. So it returns the return value from the try block.

If the `finally` block return the string after modification, then the return value field is updated again and the updated string will be returned.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid `return statement` in `try block` if you include `finally` in your code instead use it at the end of the method. Also, you can't modify the value of the returned variable in finally block. 
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3643047/6286156

Answer (score -2):

finally

finally is used in a try/catch statement to execute code "always"

```
lock.lock();
try {
  //do stuff
} catch (SomeException se) {
  //handle se
} finally {
  lock.unlock(); //always executed, even if Exception or Error or se
}
```

Java 7 has a new try with resources statement that you can use to automatically close resources that explicitly or implicitly implement java.io.Closeable or java.lang.AutoCloseable